# HttpUtils.httpConnection() refused

Tags: java, android, connection, mms, apn

I have used this code to send an mms and all parameters are correct, but the connection is refused.. And the netWork is connected on mobile mms.

HttpUtils is a class from a library downloaded here : https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms

```
HttpUtils.httpConnection(getApplicationContext(), 4444L, MMSCenterUrl, bytesToSendFromPDU, HttpUtils.HTTP_POST_METHOD, !TextUtils.isEmpty(MMSProxy), MMSProxy, port);
```

> 06-29 19:51:26.208: I/Log MMSCenterUrl(13071): http: //mmsnrj
>
> 06-29 19:51:26.208: I/Log MMSProxy(13071): 10.143.156.5
>
> 06-29 19:51:26.208: I/Log MMSPort(13071): 8080
>
> 06-29 19:51:26.288: E/Mms:transaction(13071): Url: http: //mmsnrj
>
> 06-29 19:51:26.288: E/Mms:transaction(13071): Connection to http: //10.143.156.5:8080 refused

Manifiest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Crossing out usual suspects

Uses Internet permission  in manifest file

 Server is actually up.Please send a post request form the browser using Post master or any such tool

 10.143.156.5 ip seems its an external system. Ensure that firewalls are not making your development life miserable. (Port forwarding or open the port on the routers)

Comment: I already use internet permission in manifest file but why the APN and send mms works for the default app SMS but not for my app ??